# how to write phpunit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

we have function testLink. the method $this->authorize() is invoked twice inside. How to write unit test to test business logic of invoking of method $this->authorize()?

```
public function testLink($itemId): bool
    {
        $token = $this->settingRepository->getValue(self::SETTING_ADMITAD_TOKEN);
        if ($token) {
            $this->token = $token;
        }

        if (!$this->token) {
            $this->authorize();
        }

        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 401) {
            $this->statusCode = 401;
            $this->authorize();

            $response = $this->validateLinkRequest($itemId);
        }

        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200 && json_decode($response->getContent())->message === self::ADMITAD_SUCCESS_RESPONSE) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

the sample of unit test that works in my project:

```
public function testAuthorize()
{
    $mockHttpClient = new MockHttpClient(
        [
            new MockResponse(
                json_encode([
                    "error_description" => "Token is expired",
                    "status_code" => 401,
                    "error_code" => 0,
                    "error" => "invalid_token"
                ]),
                [
                    'response_headers' => [
                        'content-type' => 'application/json',
                    ],
                    'http_code' => 401,
                ]
            ),
        ]
    );
    self::$container->set(HttpClientInterface::class, $mockHttpClient);
    $provider = self::$container->get(AdmitadDataProvider::class);
    $response = $provider->validateLinkRequest(self::ITEM_ID_1);
    $this->expectException(ClientException::class);
    $this->expectExceptionCode(401);
}
```

Comment: tests in general should only test visible behavior, usually at the interface to other code. So you shouldn't check if/how often authenticate is called, but rather, if certain test cases (failing first authentication response or whatever) would play out at the interfaces to other classes and then set the stage. That being said, if it matters how often authenticate is called (btw: at most twice and possibly not even once) you *might* have the wrong abstraction / split the code wrong. The classname "...DataProvider" to me wouldn't imply, it handles authentication itself. Just as an idea.

Comment: also, your testlink code is missing something, `$response` just appears out of thin air.